GA4 Custom Event and Parameters
We have an image on our website homepage, that has 5 Call to actions, whith which one linking to a different page (Living Room, Dining Room, Bedroom, Bathroom and Office). We want to create an GA4 custom event, and we want to know what is the best event structure to use and which conditions or parameters should be use? To create this custom event on G4, should i use an event name for different Destination page?
So far i didn't tried anything yet

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The answer is that you can do it in different ways, anyway:
You can use five different event names
or
You can use the same custom event name and enter the destinations in a parameter
or (better)
you can use the click event and populate the link_url parameter
Considering that GA4 best practices say to use the events that are already there and limit the custom ones, the latter option is the most aligned.
Learn about the click event and its parameters here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en&ref_topic=13367566&sjid=1396859295093396125-EU
